# is azure bastion compatible with virtual wan for use vnet to vnet via the virtual hub?

Tags: azure-bastion

i have an architecture with virtual wan in azure.
i would like to have a vnet with share services (app gw, az bastion, ect...) connected with a hub. arround the virtual hub i have many vnet (projects) connected like the vnet share services. I observed that it's impossible to join the vm's of the projects with azure bastion. do you know if there is a way to shre my az bastion with all the vnets connected with the virtual hub into my vwan?
in the past I used az bastion in ahub and spoke architecture with vnet peering and it worked very well.
thanks for your returns!

Comment: can you edit your question to make your question clearer?  while there is a character limit, it is usually much better to use the words in full, punctuation and white space to make your question readable.  at the moment I can't even tell what you're trying to ask

Answer (score 1):

Currently vWAN vnets doesn’t support Bastion deployments. You can only deploy Firewall as it is a Managed VNET.

If you wish you may leave your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking) All the feedback you share in these forums  will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.